# Evenly distribute within a list (Google Foobar: Maximum Equality)

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

This question comes from Google Foobar, and my code passes all but the last test, with the input/output hidden.

## The prompt

> In other words, choose two elements of the array, x[i] and x[j]
> (i distinct from j) and simultaneously increment x[i] by 1 and decrement
> x[j] by 1. Your goal is to get as many elements of the array to have
> equal value as you can.
>
> For example, if the array was [1,4,1] you could perform the operations
> as follows:
>
> Send a rabbit from the 1st car to the 0th: increment x[0], decrement
> x[1], resulting in [2,3,1] Send a rabbit from the 1st car to the 2nd:
> increment x[2], decrement x[1], resulting in [2,2,2].
>
> All the elements are of the array are equal now, and you've got a
> strategy to report back to Beta Rabbit!
>
> Note that if the array was [1,2], the maximum possible number of equal
> elements we could get is 1, as the cars could never have the same
> number of rabbits in them.
>
> Write a function answer(x), which takes the array of integers x and
> returns the maximum number of equal array elements that we can get, by
> doing the above described command as many times as needed.
>
> The number of cars in the train (elements in x) will be at least 2,
> and no more than 100. The number of rabbits that want to share a car
> (each element of x) will be an integer in the range [0, 1000000].

## My code

```
from collections import Counter

def most_common(lst):
    data = Counter(lst)
    return data.most_common(1)[0][1]

def answer(x):
    """The goal is to take all of the rabbits in list x and distribute
    them equally across the original list elements."""
    total = sum(x)
    length = len(x)
    # Find out how many are left over when distributing niavely.
    div, mod = divmod(total, length)
    # Because of the variable size of the list, the remainder
    # might be greater than the length of the list.
    # I just realized this is unnecessary.
    while mod > length:
        div += length
        mod -= length
    # Create a new list the size of x with the base number of rabbits.
    result = [div] * length
    # Distribute the leftovers from earlier across the list.
    for i in xrange(mod):
        result[i] += 1
    # Return the most common element.
    return most_common(result)
```

It runs well under my own testing purposes, handling one million tries in ten or so seconds. But it fails under an unknown input.

Have I missed something obvious, or did I make an assumption I shouldn't have?

Comment: Could you comment your code a bit? I don't know why you're doing what you're doing.

Comment: Does foobar tell you whether you failed by giving a wrong answer or by taking too long?

Comment: @Adam -- the way I read this, [4, 4, 4] *is* the correct solution: it gives 3 cars with the same number, rather than 2.

Comment: @AdamSmith It clearly says - *by doing the above described command as many times as needed.* . Not just 2 times.

Comment: Ahhh you're right, I can't read. I was thinking about progressing pairwise with `lst[i], lst[i+1]`

Comment: Please try that edit again; you lost the code formatting.

Comment: @redtuna, it tells you both. An earlier version triggered `Time limit exceeded.` This one only says, `Test X passed!` until `Test 5 failed!`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sorry, but your code doesn't work in my testing.  I fed it [0, 0, 0, 0, 22] and got back a list of [5, 5, 4, 4, 4] for an answer of 3; the maximum would be 4 identical cars, with the original input being one such example.  [4, 4, 4, 4, 6] would be another.  I suspect that's your problem, and that there are quite a few other such examples in the data base.

For N cars, the maximum would be either N (if the rabbit population is divisible by the number of cars) or N-1.  This seems so simple that I fear I'm missing a restriction in the problem.  It didn't ask for a balanced population, just as many car populations as possible should be equal.  In short:

```
def answer(census):
    size = len(census)
    return size if sum(census) % size == 0 else (size-1)
```

Comment: Wow, well done. I definitely overthought this one. Thanks so much! (Note: Your code needs `sum(census)` in the return.)

Comment: Thanks.  I think it comes from taking Numerical Analysis, Number Theory, and being on the school's Putnam Exam team for two years, plus a career in software QA.  I've spent a lot of time looking for back doors.

Comment: The instructions for the problem indicate that you should return the maximum number of cars possible "by doing the above described command as many times as needed" meaning adding or subtracting from x[i] while simultaneously subtracting or adding to x[j] where i <> j. While determining if the number of rabbits is odd or even will give you len(x) - 1 or len(x) respectively, it doesn't necessarily satisfy the spirit of the problem (to actually distribute the rabbits).

Comment: Perhaps not, although I question the "spirit" of a problem description that includes superfluous operations.  The solution above can be easily altered to handle individual movement.  First compute the target number of rabbits needed in cars 1:(N-1).  Iterate j through the array; each time census[j] > target, find the lowest i such that census[i] < target.  Move rabbits until one of the cars hits the target value.  Increase the sated index to the next qualifying car.  Continue until the penultimate car has the target number of rabbits.